# Nuxt & Three.js requestAnimationFrame Easing

Tags: vue.js, three.js, nuxt.js, requestanimationframe

I'm using Nuxt to add a simple transition to a three.js scene and I want to add easing but I'm struggling.

Here are my CURRENT working methods (without easing)

Methods:

```
frameAnimate () {
      this.time++
      this.pointCloud.rotation.x += 0.02
      this.pointCloud.rotation.y += 0.02
      this.pointCloudTwo.rotation.x += 0.02
      this.pointCloudTwo.rotation.y += 0.02
      if (this.time < 50) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.frameAnimate)
      } else if (this.time === 50) {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameAnimate)
        this.time = 0
      }
    },
```

```
colourA () {
      this.pointCloud.material.color.set('violet')
      this.frameAnimate()
    }
```

Click

```
<li @click="colourA"></li>
```

And here is MY ATTEMPT to add easing which gives me no errors but doesn't work or complete the animations.

Methods:

```
inOutQuad (n) {
      n *= 2
      if (n < 1) {
        return 0.5 * n * n
      }
      return -0.5 * (--n * (-2) - 1)
    },
```

```
frameAnimate () {
      this.time++
      this.val = this.inOutQuad(this.time)
      this.scene.rotation.y += 0.05
      this.pointCloud.rotation.x += 0.02
      this.pointCloud.rotation.y += 0.02
      this.pointCloudTwo.rotation.x += 0.02
      this.pointCloudTwo.rotation.y += 0.02
      if (this.val < 40) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.frameAnimate)
      } else if (this.val === 40) {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameAnimate)
        this.time = 0
        this.val = 0
      }
    }
```

```
colourA () {
      this.pointCloud.material.color.set('violet')
      this.frameAnimate()
    }
```

Click

```
<li @click="colourA"></li>
```

Any ideas or pointers would be much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: It seems you're confused about what `inOutQuad` does. It should be used to smooth a value between `[0, 1]`. You're not using it to smooth out any of your rotation values, and instead you're using it to abruptly stop the animation if it lands exactly on `40`. What property are you trying to apply easing to?

Comment: I just want to ease the animation in and out rather than linear `this.scene.rotation.y += 0.05`